# Unable to replace the character in string - R dataframe

Tags: r, gsub

My data has a text column that has 3000 reviews. Below is the snapshot

[image]

Reviews consist of a dollar (ex: $30 etc), I would like to replace $ into "dollarsign". My data has stored as a review and below code I used

```
reviews$text <- as.character(reviews$text)
reviews$text <- str_replace_all(reviews$text, "$", "dollarsign")
print(reviews$text)
```

I am not getting any error from the above code, however, $ sign is not replacing. "dollarsign" appears at end of the each review

[image]

I used "gsub" function as well but not successful. Please advise

Comment: Try escaping it `"\\$"`. Alternatively, set `fixed = TRUE` in `gsub`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Roland says, the answer is:

```r
library(tidyverse)

str_replace_all("I don't need to pay almost $100.", fixed("$"), "dollarsign")
#> [1] "I don't need to pay almost dollarsign100."

str_replace_all("I don't need to pay almost $100.", "\\$", "dollarsign")
#> [1] "I don't need to pay almost dollarsign100."
```